# Output flickers if I include HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, include

for my website i have some static header/footer HTML and some dynamic content generated by PHP. When it comes to render the output I just include a file with HTML inside from my PHP code. This works perfect - also when I switch between pages.

```
<?php
...
public function render() {
...
// file for output
include $fileName;
...
}
?>
```

But I also need some header.hmtl and footer.html that contains the static information (text and some divs for formating) and want to put that in front of each dynamic content, represented by $fileName.

So I simply add two includes that represent the static information.

```
// file for output
include "./Views/html/header.html";
include $fileName;
include "./Views/html/footer.html";
```

So this does what I like (formatting, etc.), but if I switch from page to page it flickers for one time. As much as I can see the page is first renderd without header/footer information and then a second time with header/footer information. Looks like this generates the flickering.

How can I avoid this ? Is this probable related to a RewriteRule of my MVC-Framework ?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: [fousc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) is a client-side thing, check where your loading styles

Comment: THX, the term FOUC led me to the solution. I put a <body><script>0</script><!-- rest of the code --></body> in  my code and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Lawrence who led me to the right term. It solved my problem completely.

I put a `<body><script>0</script><!-- rest of the code --></body>` in my code and it works now. –